# BTRF bad block force realloc

Tags: btrfs, hdparm

I have a failing hard drive, which only have 3 bad blocks. I wanted to force these blocks to reallocate but i'm unable to find the block what i have to rewrite.
Here is the error message:

> BTRFS warning (device sdb1): i/o error at logical 22670602240 on dev /dev/sdb1, physical 23752732672, root 5, inode 1737613, offset 2011136, length 4096, links 1 (path: NA....)
>
> BTRFS error (device sdb1): bdev /dev/sdb1 errs: wr 33, rd 15, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
> [577179.221511] BTRFS error (device sdb1): unable to fixup (regular) error at logical 22670602240 on dev /dev/sdb1

There is all, i've tried to use hdparm --read-sector command to try to read but i cant figure out what sector number i have to write, in order to access the bad sector.